# Change version number scheme in sfdx-project.json

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, isv, unlocked-package, 2gp

For the sake of simplicity, I want to change the default version number scheme of SFDX projects from `Major.Minor.Patch.Build` to `Major.Minor` like

```
"versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT"
```

to something like

```
"versionNumber": "1.NEXT"
```

but it won't let me do that. Is there a trick or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't currently allowed because it's not necessarily a good idea. The way versions work in Salesforce is that each version installed is tracked by the platform. Metadata that depends on a version that was never installed will fail to deploy. This creates a big cat-and-mouse type problem for subscribers of these packages.

To minimize this disruption, you're only allowed to automatically increment build numbers, which do not affect metadata dependencies. Even if you could do this, I would recommend that you don't. It may be a convenience for you, but it may artificially introduce extra work needed to update orgs with new versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible right now.

You have to manually change the minor or bug numbers to increment.

The idea was submitted to Salesforce product team over a year ago.  No eta yet.

Comment: Do you have a link to that idea ?